# Как с помощью JQuery проверить валидацию поля (по атрибуту pattern в инпуте)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

В корзине у каждого товара есть поле `number` с паттерном `[0-9]{,3}`, то есть до трех чисел. При отправке формы эти поля отлично проверяются на валидность, но есть функция обновления количества товаров, которая обновляет форму по AJAX и не имеет типа `submit`, соответственно, не может проверять введенные данные.
Как можно реализовать проверку данных по аналогичному паттерну перед обновлением формы?

Чтобы иметь представление: https://lasercut.spb.ru/pos-materialy/lototron/lototron2 добавьте товар в корзину и попробуйте там в количестве ввести невалидное значение, например `-1` и отправить форму с помощью "Оформить заказ" — проверка произойдет и форма не отправится, а если ввести `-1` и нажать на кнопку "Обновить" рядом с полем — данные отправятся по AJAX и товар просто удалится из корзины.

Как можно решить данную проблему? Спасибо.

PS Не хотелось бы юзать целый JQuery Validate ради этого, а использовать максимально простую проверку валидности.

Comment: а поле только одно? которое так надо проверять?

Comment: Grundy, да, поле одно.

Comment: приведите здесь примерную разметку вашей форму